# How to get desired result set by SQL query

Tags: sql

```
select * from employee
```

---

```
UNIT_ID  PARENT_UNIT   TOT_EMP
-------  -----------   -------
Oracle      IT           10
SAP         IT           20
IT          PST          30
HRGA        FA            5
FA          PST          12
```

How to get output as:

```
IT     60
ORACLE 10
SAP    20
HRGA    5
FA     17
```

Comment: Which dialect? MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: I do not understand how you've come up with that output. How do those numbers relate?

Comment: Note to all the quick answers the total wanted is not just that in one row but the total where the output name includes all where it is the unit or the parent + possible even more of a hierarchy

Comment: The downvote is because there was no explanation towards the calculation, no effort shown on previous work, and a really bad title.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Alright! Well said

Comment: I don't understand the logic you need.  -1.

Answer (score 4):

```
select a.name, sum(a.tot_emp)
from
(
  select unit_id as name, sum(tot_emp) as tot_emp
  from employee
  group by unit_id
  UNION
  select parent_id as name, sum(tot_emp) as tot_emp
  from employee
  group by parent_id
) as a
where exists (select null
              from employee e
              where e.unit_id = a.name)
group by name;
```

But this is not a real recursive query (which seems to be what you need), it will work with your sample, but maybe not with real datas (but we don't know the deepness of your hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know some detalis. can be in the column UNIT_ID to times the same name?
if not, this is good query:

```
select e1.UNIT_ID, SUM(TOT_EMP) AS TOT_EMP
from emploee e1
innner join emploee e2
on e1.UNIT_ID = E2.PARENT_UNIT 
group by e1.UNIT_ID
```

if can be same name in the column UNIT_ID, look in the answer of Raphaël Althaus. it's good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle query:

```
SELECT unit_id, SUM(total_emp) FROM stack_test
 GROUP BY unit_id
/
UNIT_ID    SUM(TOTAL_EMP)
--------   --------------
    SAP       50
    HRGA      15
    ORACLE    30
```

It is always good idea to create tables and populate them with values in your posts...